# install ionic 2 datepicker

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have some questions about datetime picker in ionic 2:

**1. what variable to store the datetime when i choose it?
i add my the code from my project that i just try to store it in some variables without succcessful**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {DatePicker} from 'ionic-native';
import {Calendar} from 'ionic-native';
import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';



/*
  Generated class for the InviteDates page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-invite-dates',
  templateUrl: 'invite-dates.html'
})
export class InviteDates {
  dateshow:any;
  newdate:any;
  d:any;
  b:any;
  year:any;
  month:any;
  day:any;
  today:Date;
  mydate: String = new Date().toISOString();


    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private platform:Platform) {
    this.d="";

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('Hello InviteDates Page');
    this.datefun();
  }

}
```

the html file

```
    <ion-content padding>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
        <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="mydate"></ion-datetime>
        <p> the date is :{{mydate}}</p>


    </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

in my console i get this message "datetime object" so i thought to declate datetime variable but it's shows error
[image]

**2.i want 3datetime:
  - #1 datetime of the current date
  - #2 datetime of chosen date
  - #3 datetime of the time the user chosen
how to do that?**

**3.how can i limit the dates? i mean, the user can't choose from past, just a week from today for example.**

Comment: It depends from your project structure. Usually you should put it into app.js

Comment: You can post here your project structure, then I can advice more clear answer.

Comment: You are attempting to use an Ionic 1 component with Ionic 2. In other words you are mixing Angular 1 with Angular 2. Do not do this. You should use Ionic 2s default datepicker (http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#datetime) or find an Angular 2 component to use

Comment: @Pat he specifically made a question earlier on how to NOT use datetime picker so this is a follow up

Answer (score 4):

Here is my best representation of what I believe you want to achieve (with limited formatting and styling):

Component:

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-invite-dates',
      templateUrl: 'invite-dates.html'
    })
    export class HomePage {
      date1: string = new Date().toDateString();
      date2: string;

      min: string = '';
      max: string = '';

      constructor() {
        let today = new Date();
        let oneWeek = new Date();

        oneWeek.setDate(oneWeek.getDate() + 7);

        this.min = today.toISOString();
        this.max = oneWeek.toISOString();
      }
    }
```

View:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-item>
    {{date1}}
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}" displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="date2"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    {{date2}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

Refer to the API for more details on ionic-datepicker (http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/datetime/DateTime/)

Feel free to look for 3rd party components that are built for Angular 2